# C - Invalid instruction 4

Tags: c

I am working on an app that generates then lists school records. But every time I run it keeps giving me a

> illegal instruction: 4

This is very annoying and won't go away. How can I fix this issue? Its been keeping me awake all night I've been looking all over the internet and can't find a solution.

This is the code that I am using I'm thinking its something with the arrays

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <time.h>



struct student{
    char Name[15];
    char Grade[5];
    char Age[3];
};

void GenerateStudent(int numOfStudents){

    //Setting struct
    struct student sdv[numOfStudents];

    //Setting Defult Values
    char names[50][15] = {
        "Daniel",
        "Olivia",
        "Blair",
        "Charley",
        "Tom",
        "Jim",
        "Peter",
        "Liam",
        "Tasha",
        "Marissa",
        "Alexa",
        "Ben",
        "Kylie",
        "Jasmin",
        "Jaz",
        "Merik",
        "Nathan",
        "William",
        "Lucas",
        "Mason",
        "Logan",
        "Alexander",
        "Jack",
        "Owen",
        "James",
        "Oliver",
        "Jackson",
        "Carter",
        "Ryan",
        "Matthew",
        "Emma",
        "Ava",
        "Sophia",
        "Charlotte",
        "Emily",
        "Abigail",
        "Chloe",
        "Isabella",
        "Avery",
        "Ella",
        "Lily",
        "Amelia",
        "Hannah",
        "Sofia",
        "Grace",
        "Victoria",
        "Maya",
        "Audrey",
        "Evelyn",
        "Nolan"

    };
    char grades[5][5] = {"A","B","C","D","F"};
    int ages[] = {5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17};

    int nameNum,gradeNum,ageNum;

    //Getting Rand seed using time
    time_t t;

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    for(int i = 0;i < numOfStudents;i++){
        //Generating Rand #
        nameNum = rand() % 50 + 1;
        gradeNum = rand() % 5 + 1;
        ageNum = rand() % 13;

        //Writing Values to Array
        strcpy(sdv[i].Name, names[nameNum]);
        strcpy(sdv[i].Grade, grades[gradeNum]);
        sprintf(sdv[i].Age, "%d", ages[ageNum]);
    }

    //Make sure you make a file called student_records.txt so you get the output of this app
    FILE * fpointer = fopen("school_records.txt", "a");

    printf("Writing to file...\n");

    for(int n = 0;n < numOfStudents;n++){
        //Printing Records into the file        
        fprintf(fpointer, "Name: %s     Age: %s     Avg Grade: %s\n", sdv[n].Name,sdv[n].Age,sdv[n].Grade);
    }

    //Removing the file from memory and saving changes
    printf("Done!\n");
    fclose(fpointer);
};

void mainMenu(){
    printf("---------------Main Menu---------------\n");
    printf("█████▒▒ 1.Generate Students\n");
    printf("█████▒▒ 2.Clear Records\n");
    printf("█████▒▒ 3.Exit\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------\n");
}

void genMenu(){
    printf("-------------Generate Menu-------------\n");
    printf("Enter # of records you want to make\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------\n");
}

void cleanMenu(){
    printf("--------------Clear Menu---------------\n");
    printf("Are you sure that you want to delete\nall information from the file?\n[Y]es or [N]o\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------\n");
}


int main(){
    //Declaring Variables

    //We cant leave this one unasigned just becuase it can cause an error if the use types 0
    int recordRequests = 1;
    int i,entOption;
    int exitNum = 0;
    while(exitNum == 0){
        mainMenu();
        printf("Enter Option: ");
        scanf("%d", &entOption);

        if(entOption == 1){
            printf("\n\n\n");
            genMenu();
            printf("Enter Value: ");
            scanf("%d", &recordRequests);

            GenerateStudent(recordRequests);
        }else if(entOption == 2){
            char ans;
            int loopExit = 0;
            cleanMenu();
            printf("Enter Value: ");
            scanf("&c", ans);

            if(ans == 'Y'){
                printf("Cleaning file...\n");
                FILE * fpointer = fopen("school_records.txt", "w");
                //Printing Records into the file        
                fprintf(fpointer,"");
                //Removing the file from memory and saving changes
                fclose(fpointer);
                printf("Clean sucsessful!\nReturning to menu...\n");
                loopExit = 0;
            }else if(ans == 'N'){
                    printf("Sending back to main menu...\n\n\n");
                    loopExit = 1;
                }else{
                    printf("Invalid Option Please type Y for yes or N for no\n");
                }
            }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does stepping through the code in the debugger tell you?

Comment: Hint: In `c`, arrays are zero based. The first element of an array has index zero.

Comment: Hint number 2: Strings are null terminated. So to hold a string of length 2 you need at least  3 `char`. (two for the string, and one for the null-byte)

Comment: @KenWhite I'm using vs code so debugger doesn't really work on an input based app

Comment: @HAL9000 Nvm its still showing it

Comment: The line `for(int i = 0;i <= numOfStudents;i++){` seems wrong to me. It should be '<', not '<='. Otherwise, you write past the end of the array by one element.

Comment: Then start commenting code and adding printf statements to narrow it down. Dumping dozens of lines of code here and saying *Debug this for me* isn't how this site works.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I changed it but still no effect

Comment: @KenWhite K will try to add more printf to the document

Comment: Please describe your error more clearly than "Invalid instruction 4", as that means nothing to me. Furthermore, why do you use a `char Age[2];` instead of an `int`, especially when the string "13" needs three characters.

Comment: As has been hinted by someone else in another comment, the three lines that are commented by `//Generating Rand #` are wrong. After the modulo operation, the indexes are 0-based. By adding one, you make the indexes 1-based. You then use these indexes for accessing the names, grades and ages arrays. However, in C, in contrast to several other programming languages, array indexes must be 0-based.

Comment: Reasonably good code. Just don't move too fast...

Comment: In the function main, you assign the value 0 to exitNum and then set the for loop condition so that it continues as long as exitNum stays 0. However, you never assign a different value to exitNum. Therefore, you effectively have an infinite loop.

Comment: I also get an error #4 when running the program on Microsoft compiler. It says "Run-Time Check Failure #4" and it complains about stack corruption near the variable-length array. I was able to fix this by adding space for the terminating null character by changing `char Age[2];` to `char Age[3];`, as has already been hinted by several other people.

Comment: Was "illegal instruction: 4" literally the error message you got?

Answer (score 2):

I believe I was able to reproduce your problem. When I run your code on my Microsoft compiler, I get a "Run-Time Check Failure #4" complaining about stack corruption near the variable-length array. I was able to fix this by adding space for the terminating null character by changing `char Age[2];` to `char Age[3];`, as has already been hinted by several other people in the comments section.

The problem was that the following line was accessing **all three arrays** out of bounds:

`sprintf(sdv[i].Age, "%d", ages[ageNum]);`

1. It is accessing the array `sdv` out of bounds, because `i` is in the range `[0..numOfStudents]`, but it should be in the range `[0..numOfStudents-1]`. This can be fixed by replacing the line `for(int i = 0;i <= numOfStudents;i++){` with `for(int i = 0;i < numOfStudents;i++){`.
2. It is accessing the array `sdv[i].Age` out of bounds. That array is declared as a char array of length 2. However, the maximum string length is 3. For example, the string `"14"` requires a char array of length 3 for storage, because it also requires space for the terminating null character. This can be fixed by replacing the line `char Age[2];` with `char Age[3];` in the declaration of the student struct.
3. It is accessing the array `ages` out of bounds, because ageNum is in the range `[1..13]`, but it should be in the range `[0..12]`. This is because, in the programming language C, array indexes are 0-based, in contrast to some other programming languages, which have 1-based array indexes. This can be fixed by changing the line `ageNum = rand() % 13 + 1` to `ageNum = rand() % 13;`. Also, the `+1` must be removed for the same reason from the two lines above that line.

Most likely, what I described as #2 is causing the stack memory corruption. However, all three out of bounds array accesses cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so theoretically, any one of these could be the problem.

Additonally, your program contains the following bug:

In the function main, you assign the value `0` to `exitNum` and then set the for loop condition so that it continues as long as `exitNum` stays `0`. However, you never assign a different value to `exitNum`. Therefore, you effectively have an infinite loop, making it impossible to exit your program from the main menu.

Comment: I tried all the things that you pointed out but still, it's giving me the ```Illegal instruction: 4```. Can this be because I'm on mac? if so how can i fix it?

Comment: It now says in your code `char Age[3];` and you still have the same error? Are you absolutely certain? That is what fixed it for me.

Comment: Since my Microsoft Compiler (Visual Studio 2017) does not support variable-length arrays, I additionally had to replace the line `struct student sdv[numOfStudents];` with `struct student *sdv = (struct student *)_alloca( sizeof( struct student ) * numOfStudents );`. You may want to try the same and include the appropriate header for `alloca`.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add your new code at the bottom (without deleting your previous code), stating that you still have the problem after all the reported bugs have been fixed. That way, I will be able to verify whether you fixed the bugs properly. Please post the new code seperately from the previous code. If appropriate, we can delete the code again later.

Comment: Since variable-length arrays are optional according to the latest C standard, your compiler may not support them (mine doesn't). That is why I was forced to use the workaround I posted above. However, the function alloca or _alloca, which I used as a workaround, also isn't part of the C standard, even if most compilers implement it. Therefore, that may also not work. You will have to look up alloca in your compiler documentation to see whether it is supported and which header to include. What compiler are you using on your Mac?

Comment: k will post the new updated code. I started work on another section so ignore that for now

Comment: You have now overwritten your original code. I don't think you're supposed to do that, because that makes the question and my answer useless for everyone else. That's why I had asked you not to delete your previous code. Oh well, we can fix that later, let's first find out what is wrong with your program.

Comment: Instead of spamming the comments section with extended discussion, I think we should resolve this in chat. I have opened a [new stackoverflow chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202134/c-invalid-instruction-4) for this purpose.

Comment: I am not sure if you require more reputation points in order to participate in chat. If not, then I may have to whitelist you in order for you to participate. I have posted some further information in the chat on what is wrong with your program.

Comment: It appears that you must first join the chat room before I can whitelist you to post inside it. I must go to bed now and you don't seem to have entered the chatroom yet, so I have updated my answer with what is still missing. I have added a sentence to #3 of my answer. The +1 must also be removed from the other two lines.

Comment: Before you attempt to use alloca, I suggest you first try to remove the +1 on the other two lines as mentioned above.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel `_alloca` is bad. You should use `malloc` and `free`, they work on things other than MSVC.